# Achieving a bounce effect on text using jquery animate()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use Jquery to create a bounce effect, this is what i have so far:

Html:

```
<div id ="animation">bounce</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$("#animation").animate({ marginTop: "80px" }, 1500 )
               .animate({ marginBottom: "40px" }, 800 );
```

Its goes downwards but not upwards, i tried searching the documentation, but it doesn't

working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/zLw8F/

Comment: Hi, just wanted to drop this link: [jQuery.fx.interval](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.interval/). Could not post my answer before you deleted your other question. Maybe you can tweak it a little. However, I think jQuery optimizes the animations quite well (using native features where available etc.). Try to avoid running too many animations at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To go upwards again, you'd need to reduce the `margin-top` instead of animating `margin-bottom`:

```
$("#animation").animate({ marginTop: "80px" }, 1500 )
               .animate({ marginTop: "40px" }, 800 );
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zLw8F/)

Yet, to animate the element decoupled from the rest of the page, I recommend relative positioning instead of playing with margins.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use the [jQuery UI effects](http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/)? Ex:

```
$("#animation").effect("bounce", { times:3 }, 300);​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zLw8F/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try that:

```
$("#animation").animate({ marginTop: "80px" }, 1500, function() {
  $(this).animate({ marginTop: "40px" }, 800 );
});
```